# Load UIStoryboard from another target

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, uistoryboard

I'm trying to load a storyboard what is situated in another target then the main target. But I can't get it loaded. At the moment i'm trying to do it like this.

```
private class func datePickerViewControllerFromStoryboard() -> DatePickerViewController {
    let storyboardName = "DatePicker"
    let storyboardBundle = NSBundle(forClass: self)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: storyboardBundle)
    return storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! DatePickerViewController
}
```

But this is not working. I always get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'DatePicker' in bundle NSBundle
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Did you add the storyboard file to the target? If not, then please do it.

Comment: I've selected the right target on where the storyboard is situated. Or what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean, select your storyboard file, and make sure you have checked the right target in target membership.

Comment: Is the target building a bundle, or is the storyboard being copied into the main bundle?